# How to test SQL for validity from the command line?

Tags: sql, validation, command-line, ansi-sql

Is there a good tool for ensuring that an SQL query is valid ANSI SQL, and optionally what DBMSs will fail to interpret it?  I've found http://developer.mimer.com/validator but I was wondering whether there is a command line tool, preferably open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [SQL Library](http://sqlparser.com/features/sql-formatter.php) that can help you to do [vendor-specific offline SQL syntax check](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/vendor-specific-offline-sql-syntax-check/) via command line, both Java and .NET demo were available.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a parser/generator like ANTLR or JavaCC has an ANSI SQL 92 grammar already built.  If so, you can run the parser/generator, build the classes that come out, and Bob's your uncle.

I see that ANTLR [has one](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) that's based on Oracle PL/SQL.  Maybe that can help you.  ANTLR is a terrific tool, well worth knowing.