# Syntax Checker and Validator for SQL?

Tags: sql

Is there something like lint (syntax checker and validator) for SQL?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399978/how-to-test-sql-for-validity-from-the-command-line

Comment: Following helped for validation - https://www.javainuse.com/sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a project  : [SQLLint - Detecting Semantic Errors in SQL Queries](http://dbs.informatik.uni-halle.de/sqllint/),  but I'm not sure how good it is.

Comment: This looks interesting and promising. Thanks for the link.

Comment: But after I tried it, looks not useful and not worked well. I've tried with SQL Server 2008 R2 script, the perl script itself also causes many warnings. The latest release is (27.04.2005)

Answer (score 1):

I personally love HeidiSQL editor. It is lightweight and free