# Online SQL Query Syntax Checker

Tags: sql

I need an online sql query syntax validator.

I searched online but didn't find anything good.

I saw the references in this question too:

[Syntax Checker and Validator for SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138022/syntax-checker-and-validator-for-sql)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399978/how-to-test-sql-for-validity-from-the-command-line

Comment: I tried sqlfiddle as suggested below but it was very slow and also requires the schema (which complicates things). I found this free sql syntax checker as an alternative and it's very quick - https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator

Comment: [poorsql.com/](http://poorsql.com/), [www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/), [sql-format.com/](http://sql-format.com/), [www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/).

Comment: @DxTx +1 for poorsql.com formatter!

Comment: Had to optimize a mysql query. Found a good online tool that helped - https://www.javainuse.com/sql

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) will let you test out your queries, while it doesn't explicitly correct syntax etc. per se it does let you play around with the script and will definitely let you know if things are working or not.

Comment: it checks syntax only if sql is short - 8000 chars

Comment: MySQL is not using SQL synthax. Do you know a real SQL validator?

Comment: MySQL is the default but there are 7 different SQL platforms, just use the dropdown to pick the one you need..

Comment: I tried sqlfiddle and it was very slow and also requires the schema (which complicates things). I found this free sql syntax checker as an alternative and it's very quick - https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: I like, EverSQL, as suggested by Tom Shir, has a very clean, simple to use interface. No need to define a schema or connect to a database. It is primarily for mysql but more broadly useful. If you want it to suggest optimizations too, you'll need to register (for free).  Also found this similar web app: https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Comment: The URL for EverSQL is: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: Adding a -1 because the link is dead.

Comment: @Paul Rey hmm after 7 years I wouldn't be surprised but it seems it was a temporary disruption it's up for me now

Comment: @serakfalcon You're right

Answer (score 8):

A lot of people, including me, use sqlfiddle.com to test SQL.

Comment: try 
EverSQL
dbForge Studio
SQLFiidle
https://ssiddique.info/list-of-best-sql-syntax-checker-and-sql-syntax-validator.html